# Zip two lists with diminishing lengths

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I got the below problem statement that should be solved with scala:
Two list of elements, size of first one less than the second one. For instance list 1 have 2 elements & list 2 have 10 elements.
Need to map each element of list 1 with two elements of second list. The elements used for first element shouldn't be used for the second element i.e. it takes two unique elements from second list & returns the remaining elements in second list with the mapped elements list.

```
scala> val list1 = List(1,2)
list1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> val list2 = List(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
list2: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

expected output

```
(List((1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (2,6)), List(7,8,9))
```

Comment: What if `list1` has 3 elements?

Comment: every element should be mapped to n elements of list2. if the second list has no element left, then no need to map it.

Answer (score 5):

You start with repeating elements of the first list n times, flatMap the result and zip with second collection:

```scala
val list1 = List(1,2)
val list2 = List(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

val zipped = list1
  .flatMap(i => (1 to list1.size).map(_ => i))
  .zip(list2) 
val result = (zipped, list2.drop(zipped.size))
```

Comment: Instead of `(1 to list1.size).map( _ => i)` you can use `List.fill(list1.size)(i)` which is easier to understand in my opinion.

Comment: @Ava yes, it was my original thought but personally I'm more accustomed to variant in answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is the kind of problem that I personally prefer to solve using a tail-recursive approach.

```scala
/** Zips two lists together by taking multiple elements from the second list
  * for each element of the first list.
  *
  * @param l1 The first (small) list.
  * @param l2 The second (big) list.
  * @param n The number of elements to take of second list for each element of teh first list,
  *          must be greater than zero.
  * @return A pair of the zipped list with the remaining elements of the second list,
  *         wrapped in an option to catch the possibility than the second list was consumed before finishing.
  */
def zipWithLarger[A, B](l1: List[A], l2: List[B])(n: Int): Option[(List[(A, B)], List[B])] = {  
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remainingA: List[A], remainingB: List[B], count: Int, acc: List[(A, B)]): Option[(List[(A, B)], List[B])] =
    (remainingA, remainingB) match {
      case (a :: as, b :: bs) =>
        val newElement = (a, b)
        if (count == n)
          loop(remainingA = as, remainingB = bs, count = 1, newElement :: acc)
        else
          loop(remainingA, remainingB = bs, count + 1, newElement :: acc)
      
      case (Nil, _) =>
        Some(acc.reverse -> remainingB)
      
      case (_, Nil) =>
        // We consumed the second list beforing finishing the first one.
        None
    }

  // Ensure n is positive.
  if (n >= 1) loop(remainingA = l1, remainingB = l2, count = 1, acc = List.empty)
  else None
}
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/05CIRsjYRHy0KyNgnvCJuQ/3)*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It helps my query, but I've got a query. Is it possible to keep track of tail-recursion ?? I want to know how many tail recursions occurred at the end of a function.

Comment: @SarathChandraVema sure, just add an extra parameter to keep track of the calls and return that at the end.